# How do I remove everything beyond the second occurrence of a character using Regex?

Tags: regex, filter, notepad++

I have a list that is something like:

```
xxxxx|xxxxxx|xxxxx@example.com
xxxxx|xxxxxx|xxxxx@example.com
xxxxx|xxxxxx|xxxxx@example.com
```

The x's can be both letters and numbers, but nothing else.

What I am trying to do is replace everything (including the character) to the right of the second `|`. The outcome should look like:

```
xxxxx|xxxxx
```

I want to do it with regex so that I can replace all the occurrences in Notepad++.

Answer (score 7):

Find

```
^([^|]*|[^|]*)|.*$
```

Replace with

```
\1
```

Reference: http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html

Answer (score 4):

Replace `\|[^\|]+$` with nothing.

This will match `|xxxxx@example.com`, so if you replace it with a blank string, that will accomplish what you want.

Comment: That works only if the anything after the second pipe `|` does not include another pipe.

Comment: @Jonathan, that is correct but according to the question there will only be letters or numbers in place of the `x`s, and then there will be an `@` and a `.`.

Comment: And I've got a nice bridge in Brooklyn that I can sell you :D

Comment: I understand your point, and believe in programming defensively, but the question was about a very specific scenario using a text editor replace function. Sometimes you need to cover every possible scenario and watch your back, but sometimes you are doing a one off task which just requires a quick and simple solution...